# Shift_JIS コードの表記で大文字小文字の違いは？

Tags: 文字コード, shift-jis

シフトJIS(Shift_JIS)コード表に例えば”あ”について”829f”とある場合と、”829F”と表記されている場合がありますが、この最後の `f` のShift_JISは大文字でも小文字でもどちらでも可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

どの開発言語の話をしているのかは分かりませんが、ただの2バイト数値の16進数表現なので、
大抵の開発言語は、16進数表記の大文字小文字どちらでも認識できるのではないでしょうか。
C系列だと、0x829F のように、先頭に0xを付けて16進数だということを示す必要があります。
ダブルクォーテーションで囲むと文字列と認識されるので、別の意味になります。